# How handle multiple functions in puppeteer-cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I have a two step program :

1. Get a list of href from a page
2. Loop infinitely on each page of this list, get an element and display it in console

I try to use function with Puppeteer-Cluter but it doesn't work properly.

```
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');
const fs = require("fs");
const { addExtra } = require("puppeteer-extra");
const vanillaPuppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

var moment = require('moment');
var regexTemps = /(\d+)\s(\w+)$/;
const urlsToCheck = [];

TZ = 'Europe/Paris'
process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Paris'

(async () => {
  const puppeteer = addExtra(vanillaPuppeteer);
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    puppeteer,
    puppeteerOptions: {
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    },
    maxConcurrency: 10,
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
    monitor: false,
    skipDuplicateUrls: true,
    timeout:30000,
    retryLimit:10,
  })

  cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data, willRetry) => {
      if (willRetry) {
        console.warn(`Encountered an error while crawling ${data}. ${err.message}\nThis job will be retried`);
      } else {
        console.error(`Failed to crawl ${data}: ${err.message}`);
      }
  });      

  const getElementOnPage = async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    console.log('=> Go to URL : ',url);        
    await page.goto(url);   

    while (true) {
      console.log('=> Reload URL : ',page.url())
      await page.reload();          
      await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
      let allNews = await page.$$("article.news"); // [] if nothing
      let firstNews = allNews[0];
      await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
      let info = await firstNews.$eval('.info span', s => s.textContent.trim());
      
      console.log(new Date(), 'info : ',info);
    }
  };

  const getListOfPagesToExplore = async ({ page, data: url }) => {

    console.log(new Date(), 'Get the list of deal pages to explore');        
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.waitForTimeout(500);

    const hrefsToVisit = await page.$x('//a');

    let idxTab=0;
    for( let hrefToVisit of hrefsToVisit ) {
        var link = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("href"), hrefToVisit);
        console.log(new Date(), 'adding link to list : ', link);
        idxTab++;
        urlsToCheck.push(link);            
    }
  };


  cluster.queue('https://www.apagewithsomelinks.com', getListOfPagesToExplore);
  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();    


  console.log(urlsToCheck);
  //Display correctly several link in an array

  for( let url of urlsToCheck ) {
      console.log('Push in queue : ',url);
      cluster.queue(url, getElementOnPage);
  }

  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();


})();
```

When I launch it, it retrieve the links to scrap.
It display "Push in queue : ..." for each URL.

But then, the method getElementOnPage is launched only for the first URL, and runs infinitely like asked. But why the other URL are note launched ??

Before that, I don't use function, I used one unique task with :
await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {

But how combine function and this thing ?

Comment: Probably the [concurrency settings](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#clusterlaunchoptions).

Comment: Why ? 10 concurrent browser is not enough ?